# Draggable interactive bar chart Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would love to know if building something like this is possible is RShiny. I have experience with interactive plots/charts using plotly, ggplot and ggplotly but I can't see how to do something like this. I love how the graph engages the user to make a guess and then shows the real data.

If anyone could please point me in the direction of any documentation I will be forever grateful!
https://www.mathematica-mpr.com/dataviz/race-to-the-top

[image]

Comment: Do you need the double bars? Or something [like this](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/OQePOB) would be enough?

Comment: I do like the link you showed and that is definitely a start if that is possible to do with r shiny?@StéphaneLaurent

Comment: library([rAmCharts](https://datastorm-open.github.io/introduction_ramcharts/shiny.html)) is available on CRAN but draggable bar charts don't seem to be implemented out of the box. Just fyi: here is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280032/draggable-line-chart-in-r-shiny) about line charts.

Comment: thank you @ismirsehregal rAmCharts looks cool and has some interesting features but I don't know how to incorporate the draggable barcharts based on their example code. Thanks for showing me the related question.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Do you know how I would incorporate the draggable charts you suggested into a rshiny app would it be by including a .js file and then referencing the output in the app.R file? Sorry still quite new to all of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a Shiny implementation of [this jsfiddle](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/OQePOB).

```r
library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)

barChartInput <- function(inputId, width = "100%", height = "400px", 
                          data, category, value, minValue, maxValue, 
                          color = "rgb(208,32,144)"){
  tags$div(id = inputId, class = "amchart", 
           style = sprintf("width: %s; height: %s;", width, height),
           `data-data` = as.character(toJSON(data)),
           `data-category` = category, 
           `data-value` = value,
           `data-min` = minValue,
           `data-max` = maxValue,
           `data-color` = color)
}

dat <- data.frame(
  country = c("USA", "China", "Japan", "Germany", "UK", "France"),
  visits = c(3025, 1882, 1809, 1322, 1122, 1114)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"),
    tags$script(src = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"),
    tags$script(src = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"),
    tags$script(src = "barchartBinding.js")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8, 
           barChartInput("mybarchart", data = dat, 
                         category = "country", value = "visits",
                         minValue = 0, maxValue = 3500)),
    column(4, 
           tags$label("Data:"),
           verbatimTextOutput("data"), 
           br(),
           tags$label("Change:"),
           verbatimTextOutput("change"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output[["data"]] <- renderPrint({ 
    if(is.null(input[["mybarchart"]])){
      dat
    }else{
      fromJSON(input[["mybarchart"]]) 
    }
  })

  output[["change"]] <- renderPrint({ input[["mybarchart_change"]] })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The file **barchartBinding.js**, to put in the **www** subfolder of the app file:

```js
var barchartBinding = new Shiny.InputBinding();

$.extend(barchartBinding, {
    find: function (scope) {
      return $(scope).find(".amchart");
    },
    getValue: function (el) {
      return null;
    },
    subscribe: function (el, callback) {
      $(el).on("change.barchartBinding", function (e) {
        callback();
      });
    },
    unsubscribe: function (el) {
      $(el).off(".barchartBinding");
    },
    initialize: function (el) {

      var id = el.getAttribute("id");
      var $el = $(el);
      var data = $el.data("data");
      var dataCopy = $el.data("data");
      var categoryName = $el.data("category");
      var valueName = $el.data("value");
      var minValue = $el.data("min");
      var maxValue = $el.data("max");
      var barColor = $el.data("color");

      am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

      var chart = am4core.create(id, am4charts.XYChart);
      chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this makes initial fade in effect

      chart.data = data;

      chart.padding(40, 40, 0, 0);
      chart.maskBullets = false; // allow bullets to go out of plot area

      var text = chart.plotContainer.createChild(am4core.Label);
      text.text = "Drag column bullet to change its value";
      text.y = 92;
      text.x = am4core.percent(100);
      text.horizontalCenter = "right";
      text.zIndex = 100;
      text.fillOpacity = 0.7;

      // category axis
      var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
      categoryAxis.title.text = categoryName;
      categoryAxis.title.fontWeight = "bold";
      categoryAxis.dataFields.category = categoryName;
      categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
      categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;

      // value axis
      var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
      valueAxis.title.text = valueName;
      valueAxis.title.fontWeight = "bold";
      // we set fixed min/max and strictMinMax to true, as otherwise value axis will adjust min/max while dragging and it won't look smooth
      valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;
      valueAxis.min = minValue;
      valueAxis.max = maxValue;
      valueAxis.renderer.minWidth = 60;

      // series
      var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
      series.dataFields.categoryX = categoryName;
      series.dataFields.valueY = valueName;
      series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
      series.tooltip.dy = -8;
      series.sequencedInterpolation = true;
      series.defaultState.interpolationDuration = 1500;
      series.columns.template.strokeOpacity = 0;

      // label bullet
      var labelBullet = new am4charts.LabelBullet();
      series.bullets.push(labelBullet);
      labelBullet.label.text = "{valueY.value.formatNumber('#.')}";
      labelBullet.strokeOpacity = 0;
      labelBullet.stroke = am4core.color("#dadada");
      labelBullet.dy = -20;

      // series bullet
      var bullet = series.bullets.create();
      bullet.stroke = am4core.color("#ffffff");
      bullet.strokeWidth = 3;
      bullet.opacity = 0; // initially invisible
      bullet.defaultState.properties.opacity = 0;
      // resize cursor when over
      bullet.cursorOverStyle = am4core.MouseCursorStyle.verticalResize;
      bullet.draggable = true;

      // create hover state
      var hoverState = bullet.states.create("hover");
      hoverState.properties.opacity = 1; // visible when hovered

      // add circle sprite to bullet
      var circle = bullet.createChild(am4core.Circle);
      circle.radius = 8;

      // while dragging
      bullet.events.on("drag", event => {
        handleDrag(event);
      });

      bullet.events.on("dragstop", event => {
        handleDrag(event);
        var dataItem = event.target.dataItem;
        dataItem.column.isHover = false;
        event.target.isHover = false;
        dataCopy[dataItem.index][valueName] = dataItem.values.valueY.value;
        Shiny.setInputValue(id, JSON.stringify(dataCopy));
        Shiny.setInputValue(id + "_change", {
          index: dataItem.index,
          category: dataItem.categoryX, 
          value: dataItem.values.valueY.value
        });
      });

      function handleDrag(event) {
        var dataItem = event.target.dataItem;
        // convert coordinate to value
        var value = valueAxis.yToValue(event.target.pixelY);
        // set new value
        dataItem.valueY = value;
        // make column hover
        dataItem.column.isHover = true;
        // hide tooltip not to interrupt
        dataItem.column.hideTooltip(0);
        // make bullet hovered (as it might hide if mouse moves away)
        event.target.isHover = true;
      }

      // column template
      var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
      columnTemplate.column.cornerRadiusTopLeft = 8;
      columnTemplate.column.cornerRadiusTopRight = 8;
      columnTemplate.fillOpacity = 0.8;
      columnTemplate.tooltipText = "drag me";
      columnTemplate.tooltipY = 0; // otherwise will point to middle of the column

      // hover state
      var columnHoverState = columnTemplate.column.states.create("hover");
      columnHoverState.properties.fillOpacity = 1;
      // you can change any property on hover state and it will be animated
      columnHoverState.properties.cornerRadiusTopLeft = 35;
      columnHoverState.properties.cornerRadiusTopRight = 35;

      // show bullet when hovered
      columnTemplate.events.on("over", event => {
        var dataItem = event.target.dataItem;
        var itemBullet = dataItem.bullets.getKey(bullet.uid);
        itemBullet.isHover = true;
      });

      // hide bullet when mouse is out
      columnTemplate.events.on("out", event => {
        var dataItem = event.target.dataItem;
        var itemBullet = dataItem.bullets.getKey(bullet.uid);
        itemBullet.isHover = false;
      });

      // start dragging bullet even if we hit on column not just a bullet, this will make it more friendly for touch devices
      columnTemplate.events.on("down", event => {
        var dataItem = event.target.dataItem;
        var itemBullet = dataItem.bullets.getKey(bullet.uid);
        itemBullet.dragStart(event.pointer);
      });

      // when columns position changes, adjust minX/maxX of bullets so that we could only dragg vertically
      columnTemplate.events.on("positionchanged", event => {
        var dataItem = event.target.dataItem;
        var itemBullet = dataItem.bullets.getKey(bullet.uid);
        var column = dataItem.column;
        itemBullet.minX = column.pixelX + column.pixelWidth / 2;
        itemBullet.maxX = itemBullet.minX;
        itemBullet.minY = 0;
        itemBullet.maxY = chart.seriesContainer.pixelHeight;
      });

      // as by default columns of the same series are of the same color, we add adapter which takes colors from chart.colors color set
      columnTemplate.adapter.add("fill", (fill, target) => {
        return barColor; //chart.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index).saturate(0.3);
      });

      bullet.adapter.add("fill", (fill, target) => {
        return chart.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index).saturate(0.3);
      });

    }
});

Shiny.inputBindings.register(barchartBinding);
```

[image]

---

## Update

And below is a Shiny implementation of the amcharts4 *grouped bar chart*.

```r
library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)

registerInputHandler("dataframe", function(data, ...) {
  fromJSON(toJSON(data, auto_unbox = TRUE))
}, force = TRUE)

groupedBarChartInput <- function(inputId, width = "100%", height = "400px", 
                                 data, categoryField, valueFields, 
                                 minValue, maxValue, 
                                 ndecimals = 0, 
                                 colors = NULL, 
                                 categoryLabel = categoryField, 
                                 valueLabels = valueFields, 
                                 categoryAxisTitle = categoryLabel,
                                 valueAxisTitle = NULL,
                                 categoryAxisTitleFontSize = 22,
                                 valueAxisTitleFontSize = 22,
                                 categoryAxisTitleColor = "indigo",
                                 valueAxisTitleColor = "indigo",
                                 draggable = rep(FALSE, length(valueFields))){
  tags$div(id = inputId, class = "amGroupedBarChart", 
           style = sprintf("width: %s; height: %s;", width, height),
           `data-data` = as.character(toJSON(data)),
           `data-categoryfield` = categoryField, 
           `data-valuefields` = as.character(toJSON(valueFields)),
           `data-min` = minValue,
           `data-max` = maxValue,
           `data-ndecimals` = ndecimals,
           `data-colors` = ifelse(is.null(colors), "auto", as.character(toJSON(colors))),
           `data-valuenames` = as.character(toJSON(valueLabels)),
           `data-categoryname` = categoryLabel,
           `data-categoryaxistitle` = categoryAxisTitle,
           `data-valueaxistitle` = valueAxisTitle,
           `data-draggable` = as.character(toJSON(draggable)),
           `data-categoryaxistitlefontsize` = categoryAxisTitleFontSize,
           `data-valueaxistitlefontsize` = valueAxisTitleFontSize,
           `data-categoryaxistitlecolor` = categoryAxisTitleColor,
           `data-valueaxistitlecolor` = valueAxisTitleColor)
}

set.seed(666)
dat <- data.frame(
  year = rpois(5, 2010),
  income = rpois(5, 25),
  expenses = rpois(5, 20)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"),
    tags$script(src = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"),
    tags$script(src = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"),
    tags$script(src = "groupedBarChartBinding.js")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8, 
           groupedBarChartInput("mybarchart", data = dat[order(dat$year),], 
                                categoryField = "year", 
                                valueFields = c("income", "expenses"),
                                categoryLabel = "Year", 
                                valueLabels =  c("Income", "Expenses"),
                                valueAxisTitle = "Income and expenses",
                                minValue = 0, maxValue = 35, 
                                draggable = c(FALSE, TRUE),
                                colors = c("darkmagenta","darkred"))),
    column(4, 
           tags$label("Data:"),
           verbatimTextOutput("data"), 
           br(),
           tags$label("Change:"),
           verbatimTextOutput("change"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output[["data"]] <- renderPrint({ 
    input[["mybarchart"]] 
  })

  output[["change"]] <- renderPrint({ input[["mybarchart_change"]] })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The file **groupedBarChartBinding.js**, to put in the **www** subfolder:

```js
var groupedBarChartBinding = new Shiny.InputBinding();

$.extend(groupedBarChartBinding, {
    find: function(scope) {
        return $(scope).find(".amGroupedBarChart");
    },
    getValue: function(el) {
        return $(el).data("data");
    },
    getType: function(el) {
        return "dataframe";
    },
    subscribe: function(el, callback) {
        $(el).on("change.groupedBarChartBinding", function(e) {
            callback();
        });
    },
    unsubscribe: function(el) {
        $(el).off(".groupedBarChartBinding");
    },
    initialize: function(el) {

        var id = el.getAttribute("id");
        var $el = $(el);
        var data = $el.data("data");
        var dataCopy = $el.data("data");
        var categoryField = $el.data("categoryfield");
        var valueFields = $el.data("valuefields");
        var minValue = $el.data("min");
        var maxValue = $el.data("max");
        var colors = $el.data("colors");
        var valueNames = $el.data("valuenames");
        var categoryName = $el.data("categoryname");
        var categoryAxisTitle = $el.data("categoryaxistitle");
        var valueAxisTitle = $el.data("valueaxistitle");
        var draggable = $el.data("draggable");
        var ndecimals = $el.data("ndecimals");
        var numberFormat = "#.";
        for (var i = 0; i < ndecimals; i++) {
            numberFormat = numberFormat + "#";
        }
        var categoryAxisTitleFontSize = $el.data("categoryaxistitlefontsize") + "px";
        var valueAxisTitleFontSize = $el.data("valueaxistitlefontsize") + "px";
        var categoryAxisTitleColor = $el.data("categoryaxistitlecolor");
        var valueAxisTitleColor = $el.data("valueaxistitlecolor");

        am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

        var chart = am4core.create(id, am4charts.XYChart);
        chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this makes initial fade in effect

        chart.data = data;

        chart.padding(40, 40, 40, 40);
        chart.maskBullets = false; // allow bullets to go out of plot area

        // Create axes
        var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
        categoryAxis.dataFields.category = categoryField;
        categoryAxis.numberFormatter.numberFormat = numberFormat;
        categoryAxis.renderer.inversed = true;
        categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
        categoryAxis.renderer.cellStartLocation = 0.1;
        categoryAxis.renderer.cellEndLocation = 0.9;
        categoryAxis.title.text = categoryAxisTitle;
        categoryAxis.title.fontWeight = "bold";
        categoryAxis.title.fontSize = categoryAxisTitleFontSize;
        categoryAxis.title.setFill(categoryAxisTitleColor);

        var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
        valueAxis.renderer.opposite = true;
        valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;
        valueAxis.min = minValue;
        valueAxis.max = maxValue;
        if (valueAxisTitle !== null) {
            valueAxis.title.text = valueAxisTitle;
            valueAxis.title.fontWeight = "bold";
            valueAxis.title.fontSize = valueAxisTitleFontSize;
            valueAxis.title.setFill(valueAxisTitleColor);
        }

        function handleDrag(event) {
            var dataItem = event.target.dataItem;
            // convert coordinate to value
            var value = valueAxis.xToValue(event.target.pixelX);
            // set new value
            dataItem.valueX = value;
            // make column hover
            dataItem.column.isHover = true;
            // hide tooltip not to interrupt
            dataItem.column.hideTooltip(0);
            // make bullet hovered (as it might hide if mouse moves away)
            event.target.isHover = true;
        }

        // Create series
        function createSeries(field, name, barColor, drag) {
            var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
            series.dataFields.valueX = field;
            series.dataFields.categoryY = categoryField;
            series.name = name;
            series.sequencedInterpolation = true;

            var valueLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
            valueLabel.label.text = "{valueX}";
            valueLabel.label.horizontalCenter = "left";
            valueLabel.label.dx = 10;
            valueLabel.label.hideOversized = false;
            valueLabel.label.truncate = false;

            var categoryLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
            categoryLabel.label.text = "{name}";
            categoryLabel.label.horizontalCenter = "right";
            categoryLabel.label.dx = -10;
            categoryLabel.label.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
            categoryLabel.label.hideOversized = false;
            categoryLabel.label.truncate = false;

            // column template
            var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
            console.log(columnTemplate);
            //  columnTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueX}[/]";
            columnTemplate.tooltipHTML =
                "<div style='font-size:9px'>" + "{name}" + ": " + "<b>{valueX}</b>" + "</div>";
            columnTemplate.height = am4core.percent(100);
            columnTemplate.column.cornerRadiusBottomRight = 8;
            columnTemplate.column.cornerRadiusTopRight = 8;
            columnTemplate.fillOpacity = 1;
            columnTemplate.tooltipX = 0; // otherwise will point to middle of the column
            // hover state
            var columnHoverState = columnTemplate.column.states.create("hover");
            columnHoverState.properties.fillOpacity = 1;
            // you can change any property on hover state and it will be animated
            columnHoverState.properties.cornerRadiusBottomRight = 35;
            columnHoverState.properties.cornerRadiusTopRight = 35;
            // color
            if (barColor !== false) {
                columnTemplate.adapter.add("fill", (fill, target) => {
                    return barColor;
                });
            }


            if (drag) {
                // series bullet
                var bullet = series.bullets.create();
                bullet.stroke = am4core.color("#ffffff");
                bullet.strokeWidth = 1;
                bullet.opacity = 0; // initially invisible
                bullet.defaultState.properties.opacity = 0;
                // resize cursor when over
                bullet.cursorOverStyle = am4core.MouseCursorStyle.horizontalResize;
                bullet.draggable = true;
                // create hover state
                var hoverState = bullet.states.create("hover");
                hoverState.properties.opacity = 1; // visible when hovered
                // add circle sprite to bullet
                var circle = bullet.createChild(am4core.Circle);
                circle.radius = 5;
                // dragging
                // while dragging
                bullet.events.on("drag", event => {
                    handleDrag(event);
                });
                bullet.events.on("dragstop", event => {
                    handleDrag(event);
                    var dataItem = event.target.dataItem;
                    dataItem.column.isHover = false;
                    event.target.isHover = false;
                    dataCopy[dataItem.index][field] = dataItem.values.valueX.value;
                    Shiny.setInputValue(id + ":dataframe", dataCopy);
                    Shiny.setInputValue(id + "_change", {
                        index: dataItem.index,
                        field: field,
                        category: dataItem.categoryY,
                        value: dataItem.values.valueX.value
                    });
                });
                // bullet color
                if (barColor !== false) {
                    bullet.adapter.add("fill", (fill, target) => {
                        return barColor;
                    });
                }
                // show bullet when hovered
                columnTemplate.events.on("over", event => {
                    var dataItem = event.target.dataItem;
                    var itemBullet = dataItem.bullets.getKey(bullet.uid);
                    itemBullet.isHover = true;
                });
                // hide bullet when mouse is out
                columnTemplate.events.on("out", event => {
                    var dataItem = event.target.dataItem;
                    var itemBullet = dataItem.bullets.getKey(bullet.uid);
                    itemBullet.isHover = false;
                });
                // start dragging bullet even if we hit on column not just a bullet, this will make it more friendly for touch devices
                columnTemplate.events.on("down", event => {
                    var dataItem = event.target.dataItem;
                    var itemBullet = dataItem.bullets.getKey(bullet.uid);
                    itemBullet.dragStart(event.pointer);
                });
                // when columns position changes, adjust minY/maxY of bullets so that we could only dragg horizontally
                columnTemplate.events.on("positionchanged", event => {
                    var dataItem = event.target.dataItem;
                    var itemBullet = dataItem.bullets.getKey(bullet.uid);
                    var column = dataItem.column;
                    itemBullet.minY = column.pixelY + column.pixelHeight / 2;
                    itemBullet.maxY = itemBullet.minY;
                    itemBullet.minX = 0;
                    itemBullet.maxX = chart.seriesContainer.pixelWidth;
                });
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < valueFields.length; i++) {
            var color = colors === "auto" ? null : colors[i];
            createSeries(valueFields[i], valueNames[i], color, draggable[i]);
        }

    }
});

Shiny.inputBindings.register(groupedBarChartBinding);
```

[image]

---

## Update 2

I have done a package now : [shinyAmBarCharts](https://github.com/stla/shinyAmBarCharts). I have added a button (optional) allowing to update the data to another dataset. This fulfills the OP's desideratum:

> the graph engages the user to make a guess and then shows the real
>   data

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyAmBarCharts)

# create a dataset
set.seed(666)
df0 <- data.frame(
  species = rep(c("sorgho","poacee","banana"), each = 3),
  condition = rep(c("normal", "stress", "Nitrogen"), 3),
  value = rpois(9, 10)
)
df1 <- df0; df1[["value"]] <- 10
dat <- tidyr::spread(df0, condition, value)  # true data
dat2 <- tidyr::spread(df1, condition, value) # data template

# grouped bar chart
ui <- fluidPage(

  br(),

  fluidRow(
    column(9,
           amBarChart(
             "mygroupedbarchart", data = dat2, data2 = dat, height = "400px",
             category = "species", value = c("normal", "stress", "Nitrogen"),
             valueNames = c("Normal", "Stress", "Nitrogen"),
             minValue = 0, maxValue = 20,
             draggable = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
             theme = "dark", backgroundColor = "#30303d",
             columnStyle = list(fill = c("darkmagenta", "darkred", "gold"),
                                stroke = "#cccccc", 
                                cornerRadius = 4),
             chartTitle = list(text = "Grouped bar chart", 
                               fontSize = 23, 
                               color = "firebrick"),
             xAxis = list(title = list(text = "Species", 
                                       fontSize = 21, 
                                       color = "silver"),
                          labels = list(color = "whitesmoke", 
                                        fontSize = 17)),
             yAxis = list(title = list(text = "Value", 
                                       fontSize = 21, 
                                       color = "silver"),
                          labels = list(color = "whitesmoke", 
                                        fontSize = 14)),
             columnWidth = 90,
             button = list(text = "Show true data"),
             caption = list(text = "[font-style:italic]shinyAmBarCharts[/]", 
                            color = "yellow"),
             gridLines = list(color = "whitesmoke", 
                              opacity = 0.4, 
                              width = 1),
             tooltip = list(text = "[bold;font-style:italic]{name}: {valueY}[/]", 
                            labelColor = "#101010", 
                            backgroundColor = "cyan", 
                            backgroundOpacity = 0.7)
           )
    ),
    column(3,
           tags$label("Data:"),
           verbatimTextOutput("data"),
           br(),
           tags$label("Change:"),
           verbatimTextOutput("change"))
  )

)

server <- function(input, output){

  output[["data"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["mygroupedbarchart"]]
  })

  output[["change"]] <- renderPrint({ input[["mygroupedbarchart_change"]] })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Okay awesome this definitely gives me something to work with, I just need to acquaint myself with some JS and I think I can make the code do what I want by incorporating a submit button and then getting another chart to appear showing the values to still get the user engagement and guesswork I was after. Thank you

Comment: @RhettaC See this gist for updates: https://gist.github.com/stla/dbe3379704f0c5a08ab4defe201a15bf

Comment: @RhettaC See my update for the grouped bar chart. And see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/stla/33d5339f4ac1c72aa9a5745611334808) for the updates.

Comment: this updates looks great. Thank you so much for sharing it. I will have a proper look at it to tomorrow morning but the flipped grouped bar chart looks awesome. The only other thing would be to have the user pull it to where they think it should be and then the actual result show after they have 'submitted' their guess, but this is good. Eg: how much do you think the population in Brisbane will increase by 2025? User adjusts bar to guessed increase and submits and then actual population number is displayed. @StéphaneLaurent

Comment: @RhettaC Forget the gists. I've done a package: [shinyAmBarCharts](https://github.com/stla/shinyAmBarCharts).

Comment: @RhettaC See my latest update in my answer. I have added a button allowing to update the data.

Comment: I am not able to download devtools::install_github("stla/shinyAmBarCharts")

Comment: @RhettaC You get an error message ? What does it say ?

Comment: devtools::install_github("stla/shinyAmBarCharts")                                                                  
Downloading GitHub repo stla/shinyAmBarCharts@master
Error in process_initialize(self, private, command, args, stdin, stdout,  : 
  Command not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers

Comment: @RhettaC Hmm not cool. I've searched with Google and you're not the only one facing this issue. But I have not found a solution. You could clone or download the Github repo and build the package with RStudio.

Comment: Okay thank you @StéphaneLaurent I will give it a go