# How to drag a plot line and back into the resulting line parameters in R Shiny?

Tags: r, plot, shiny, drag-and-drop, draggable

Here's a long-shot question. The below code allows the user to build and alter a scaled-logarithmic curve by altering its 4 parameters, via slider inputs. I'd like to reverse the process, so the user clicks/drags the plot line and a new "exponential" curve parameter is backed into. How to do this in R Shiny?

Later, after figuring out how to derive the exponential parameter, I'll try backing into some of the other curve parameters too.

This image illustrates what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sliderInput('periods','Nbr of periods:',min=0,max=36,value=24),
  sliderInput('start','Start value:',min=0,max=1,value=0.15),
  sliderInput('end','End value:',min=0,max=1,value=0.70),
  sliderInput('exponential','Exponential:',min=-100,max=100,value=10),
  plotOutput('plot')
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      Periods = c(0:input$periods),
      ScaledLog = c(
        (input$start-input$end) *
        (exp(-input$exponential/100*(0:input$periods))-
        exp(-input$exponential/100*input$periods)*(0:input$periods)/input$periods)) +
        input$end
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(data(),type='l',col='blue',lwd=5))
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: When you say  "click / drag" the plot line you mean "draw" the plot line with your mouse?

Comment: Yes, draw the line if that's possible

Comment: Please find some related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64334711/9841389), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280032/draggable-line-chart-in-r-shiny/54777145#54777145) and [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/draggging-multiple-points-using-plotly/22081/2).

Comment: Thanks, I think the second "here" in the list is the best source. I'm working on implementing that solution into my scale log example